# Can i set Remaining work and Original estimate to the same value if Original estimate is empty?

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to set up a rule, that when the value of Remaining Work on the card is changed in the Work -> Backlog view , this is propagated to the Original Estimate on the card, if empty?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thorough guide:
I installed the following marketplace module for my local VS environment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor

Then, in VS i went to Tools -> Process Editor -> Work item Types -> Open WIT from Server

Logged in to our local TFS environment

Navigated to the specific board i wanted to post a rule on

Found the WIT for "Original Estimate"

Added a new rule by right clicking on it.

The rule was of type "WHEN" and said that "WHEN" the field was empty (Had a value of "")
then the Rule defined was applied. The rule was of type "COPY" and copied the value in the "Remaining Work" field.

This worked in TFS Version 16.131.28106.2